# How to format a floating number to variable width in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing code where I would like the user to enter the desire decimal point precision. For example:

```
for x in numbers:
    print "{:10.*f}".format(x)
```

...except where the '`*`' is I would like to place a variable that which the user provided value. My search for a solution in available documentation has proved unfruitful.

Answer (score 1):

How about `print '{:10.{precision}f}'.format(x, precision=precision)`, where `precision` is a value defined elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was looking for a needle in a haystack. Was nice to have the needle come to me. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. If I helped you, please accept my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Python One-liner

```
number = 10.123456789
print ('{:10.{precision}f}'.format(number, precision=int(input("Enter the precision"))))

Output :   
>>> print ('{:10.{precision}f}'.format(number, precision=int(input("Enter the precision\n"))))
    Enter the precision
    5
      10.12346
```